# Render multiple chart simultaneously using react-chartjs-2

Tags: reactjs, react-chartjs-2

I have rendered bar chart without any errors. but while adding doughnut chart it's getting this type of error in console.
getting error when uncommenting doughnut chart component. i think the problem here is i may be missing any of the chart js register for doughnut chart.

```
react-dom.development.js:22831 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
    at setDatasets (utils.ts:57:1)
    at cloneData (utils.ts:94:1)
    at renderChart (chart.tsx:43:1)
    at chart.tsx:97:1
    at commitHookEffectListMount (react-dom.development.js:23139:1)
    at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:24917:1)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects_complete (react-dom.development.js:24880:1)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects_begin (react-dom.development.js:24869:1)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects (react-dom.development.js:24856:1)
    at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (react-dom.development.js:27029:1)
```

this is my code.
`app.js`

```
import {
  Chart as ChartJs,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  BarElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
} from  'chart.js'

import { Bar, Doughnut } from 'react-chartjs-2';

import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'

import { individual_dataset } from './data';

import {
  Container,
  NavBar,
  ConfidenceContainer,
  OutLine,
  DesigInput,
  Box,
  Option,
  ChartsContainer,
} from './style'

ChartJs.register(
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  BarElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
)



function App() {
  const [confidenceData, setConfidenceData] = useState({
    datasets: []
  })
  const [ chartOptions, setChartOptions] = useState({});

  const [gaughData, setGaughData] = useState({
    dataset:[]
  })
  const [gaughChartOptions, setGaughChartOptions] = useState({})

  const [selected, setSelected] = useState({});
  const [showList, setShowList] = useState(false);
  const handleItemChange=(item)=>{
    setSelected(item)
    setShowList(false)
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    if(selected?.name){
    setConfidenceData({
      labels: ['confidence', 'active listening', 'total'],
      datasets: [
        {
            label: 'Average',
            data: [58.05, 67.125, 125.5],
            borderColor: "rgb(53,162, 235)",
            backgroundColor: "#9EA1D4"
        },
        {
            label: 'Individual Score',
            data: [selected.total_score_confidence, selected.total_score_active_listening, selected.total_score_overall],
            borderColor: "rgb(53,162, 235)",
            backgroundColor: "#FD8A8A"
        },
        
      ]
    })
    setGaughData({
      labels:['Confidence', 'left over', 'hi'],
  datasets: [{
    label: 'My First Dataset',
    data: [300, 50, 100],
    backgroundColor: [
      'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
      'rgb(255, 205, 86)'
    ],
    hoverOffset: 4
  }],

    })
  }


    setGaughChartOptions({

    })
    setChartOptions({
      responsive: true,
      plugins: {
        scales: {
          y:{
            min: 200,
            max: 200,
            stepSize: 40, 
          }
        },
        legend:{
          position: "bottom",
          labels:{
            pointStyle: 'circle'
          }
        },
        title:{
          display: true,
          text: `Performance of ${selected?.name}`,
        }
      }
    })

  },[selected])
  

  return (
    <Container>
      <NavBar>
        <h2> {selected?.name ? `${selected.name}\'s Performance` : "Individual Performance"}</h2>
        <OutLine>
            <DesigInput onClick={()=>setShowList(!showList)}>{selected?.name?selected.name: "Select Person"}</DesigInput>
            { showList && <Box>
                <Option onClick={()=>handleItemChange()}>NONE</Option>
                {individual_dataset.map((item)=>{
                    return <Option key={item.id} onClick={()=>handleItemChange(item)} >{item.name}</Option>;
                })}
            </Box>}
        </OutLine>
      </NavBar>
      <ChartsContainer>
        { selected?.name && <ConfidenceContainer key={'confidence'}><Bar key={'confidence'} options={chartOptions}  data={confidenceData} /></ConfidenceContainer>}
        {selected?.name && <Doughnut options={gaughChartOptions} data={gaughData} />}
      </ChartsContainer>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default App;
```

example `data.js`

```
data = [

   {
      id:"1",
      name:"Shivam",
      total_score_confidence:"100",
      total_score_active_listening:"100",
      total_score_overall:"200"
   },
   {
      id:"2",
      name:"Utkarsh",
      total_score_confidence:"57",
      total_score_active_listening:"85",
      total_score_overall:"142"
   },

]
```

i need to render doughnut chart along with bar chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I can see is that you are importing the `BarElement` from chart.js and that's why your Bar chart works correctly, but you should import also `ArcElement` for Doughnut chart. Don't forget to add 'ArcElement' also to the `CharJS.register` list.

Comment: yeah. i figured it out already. Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you solved your problem yet, but I was facing the same issue when trying to render different types of charts (line, bars, doughnuts...) in the same page and I found the solution.
Import and register as follow and then you should not get the error anymore:

```
import {
    Chart as ChartJS,
    CategoryScale,
    LinearScale,
    PointElement,
    LineElement,
    BarElement,
    ArcElement,
    Tooltip,
    Legend,
    registerables as registerablesJS
} from 'chart.js';

import { Chart } from 'react-chartjs-2';

ChartJS.register(...registerablesJS);

ChartJS.register(
    CategoryScale,
    LinearScale,
    PointElement,
    LineElement,
    BarElement,
    ArcElement,
    Tooltip,
    Legend,
);
```